# Key based authentication (SFTP) failed

Tags: ssh, sftp, psftp

I created a pair or `RSA` keys using Putty key generator, The Public key is attached set on the server side.
The private key at windows client machine and being used with pageant and `FileZila` and working fine. Now Problem is that when I want to connect same sftp through PSFTP commandline tool, it failes.
if possible please provide steps to setup ssh key on windows client to access `sftp` using `psftp` or direct through batch file.

Answer (score 0):

If `pageant` is running and has the key loaded `psftp` should use it. It does on my system. Exactly how does it fail for you?
`plink` should use `pageant` the same way; does it work? How about `putty user@host` (not using a saved session)?

According to the manual http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-pubkey 
option `-i` or a saved session containing Auth should also work, but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same version of Pageant and `psftp`. Some versions are not compatible.

If this does not help, run `psftp -v` and try again and include console output to your question.

Ideally you should see something like:

> `Pageant is running. Requesting keys.`
>   `Pageant has 2 SSH-2 keys`